# Geometric Type in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgresql-9.3

I have a table as shown below:

**Example**:

In SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
create table geometrics
(
   geopath geometry
);
```

In the above table I can store geometry path it may be POLYGON, CIRCLE or may be POINT accordingly.

But In the PostgreSQL 9.3 version, I referred this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-geometric.html

I need to give each time different data types for each different geometric types.

Like:

```
create table geometrics
(
   geopoint point,
   geopath path,
   geopolygon polygon,
   geocircle circle
);
```

**My Question**: Can I give a single Geometric data type which can store any geometric type like we do in SQL Server by using geometry?

Comment: You may want to use the PostGIS spatial extension, instead of PostgreSQL's basic geometry support http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgis/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you need to install [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/), and then run

```
CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS
```

in your database